# How to copy an already created asp.net form to start creating another one (inside TFS)?

Tags: asp.net

I have a number of forms built already inside a repository. I have to copy one of those forms and use it to create another form.

How do I do that?

Comment: Is this in an ASP.NET Web Site "project", or a Web Application Project?

Comment: It's an ASP.NET Web Site "Project"...

Comment: Good to know. They're strange and I recommend they never be used except for trivial sites.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Some assistance with ASP.NET form creation...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16451143/some-assistance-with-asp-net-form-creation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Solution explorer right click the file and select copy.  Then just paste it into the same folder and rename it.  This will ready the new file to be added on next check-in

Comment: There is no copy option... Here's what I see when I right-click...

Comment: https://www.box.com/s/f8vu6fqq3fz62lwm50gx

Comment: @KoldTurkee, your screenshot is from Source Control Explorer. You should be doing this from Solution Explorer.

Comment: Yes be sure you are looking at **Solution Explorer** not "Source Control Explorer".. If you must use Source Control Explorer, go to your working folder on your HDD where your source code is pulled down from and duplicate/rename your file there.  Then add the file using Source Control Explorer.