# Some assistance with ASP.NET form creation...

Tags: asp.net, forms

I have a list of forms in my Source Control.

```
ContentRequest.aspx
ContentRequest.aspx.cs
Default.aspx
Default.aspx.vb
```

I have to use some of these forms to create additional forms, using one of the above forms as a template of sorts.

I'm not sure how to do that. Can someone provide me some guidance?

-KT

Comment: Can you be more specific with your question? I don't clearly understand your goal.

Comment: My goal is to take a form that's already been created and create another one, but changing up the content, while keeping the style and everything else the same. What I don't understand is how to copy a form that's already been created, and drop it in the same directory, under a different name, of course.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio or some other tool for your project?

Comment: @KoldTurkee how about you create 2 new identical forms, and diff them

Comment: It's VS 2010. @SamIam - I would like to do that, but I have to drop that form I have to create inside the same directory that the other forms are in. ASP is so new to me... obvious learning curve... I don't even see how to create a new form in this directory...

Comment: @KoldTurkee check my answer below, it should be helpful.

Comment: CTRL+C then CTRL+V.  Rename as necessary...

Comment: I should also note that I'm not using Solution Explorer... I'm using TFS, so I'm in Team Explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create a copy of the whole ASPX form you want to duplicate. In VS, right click on your project(website) in Solution explorer -> Add -> New -> Web Form. Name it `NewName`. Then copy from Default.aspx to NewName.aspx and do the same with aspx.cs files.

Then you have to change the source code of NewName.aspx file on the first line:

```
CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" -> CodeFile="NewName.aspx.cs" Inherits="_NewName"
```

and in NewName.aspx.cs file:

```
class _Default : Page -> class _NewName : Page
```

Comment: I tried doing what you said... this is what I see when I right click on the project... https://www.box.com/s/le4o1mb71zosb7ieenii

Comment: I should also note that I'm not using Solution Explorer... I'm using TFS, so I'm in Team Explorer.

Comment: So, the issue was that my project wasn't mapped to my local disk. I think the issue is fixed now.

Comment: So is it working now? If it is, check one of answers as correct or provide your own correct answer to close the question.

Comment: The issue was that I am using TFS and hadn't mapped the Source file to my local drive. Once I did that, then I was able to follow your instructions without further issues. Much thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Copy Paste is a good start if you're just duplicating ASPX files. If you need to be a little more detailed (and do it the right way), then you should consider using a [master page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for the theme/layout and then create new forms that inherit from it.

Layout.master

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 
    1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server" >
    <title>Master page title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <table>
           <tr>
               <td><asp:contentplaceholder id="Main" runat="server" /></td>
               <td><asp:contentplaceholder id="Footer" runat="server" /></td>
           </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

ContentRequest.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/Layout.master" Title="Content Request"%>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Main" Runat="Server">
    Main content.
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="Footer" Runat="Server" >
    Footer content.
</asp:content>
```

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/Layout.master" Title="Default"%>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Main" Runat="Server">
    Main content.
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="Footer" Runat="Server" >
    Footer content.
</asp:content>
```

Comment: I think you're on the right track now. There's a Master Page here... I see it's labeled MasterPage.master, but I am not sure how to create a new form from this... Trying to learn this on my own, without bugging co-workers... I'm the newbie.

Comment: when you create a new aspx page, you can check a checkbox to use a master page. Just point to the one already created.

Comment: I'm trying to create a new page, but there's no Add Item option when I right-click on the project name...  Here's what I see - https://www.box.com/s/elxnw4gax42fgiv07p0p

Comment: I'm not familiar with your source control, I use GIT, and when I create a new file, I do it locally and then commit it to my DVCS... IE: I don't create a new file **IN** my source control.

Comment: The problem (and I assume this was a VS issue) is that my project hadn't been mapped to my computer. It was on the server and I can't work off the server... I've mapped it and now I'm good. Thanks, Chase! PS-Canada rocks!